# How to remotely access an neo4j community container running on azure with python(neo4j module)?

Tags: python, database, azure, neo4j, neo4j-driver

There is a neo4j community version container running on the azure, and i was provided by the dns

> http://[remote-address]:7687

if i do curl with proxy(px from github)(office recommended also), i able to get, bolt_routing, transaction, bolt_direct, neo4j_version, neo4j_edition all successfully,

And with 7474 port with web browser i also able to connect to the db and same with neo4j desktop by adding remote db.

but when i do with python neo4j driver, **Cannot resolve address [remote-address]:7687**

```
import neo4j,sys
link = "bolt://" + sys.argv[1]
print(f"Trying to connect to:  {link}")

def exp():
    try:
        x = neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver(link, auth=("neo4j", "my_pswd"))

        print(x.verify_connectivity())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

so, how to connect to a container hosted on azure ?

Update:

i tried to connect with IP of the azure instance running, but

> Couldn't connect to [IP-address]:7687 (resolved to ('[IP-address]:7687',)):

> Failed to establish connection to ResolvedIPv4Address(('[IP-address]', 7687)) (reason [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)

it is connection through web and neo4j browser completely fine, only not through the python script.!!

Comment: The examples in the docs use `neo4j://` instead of `bolt://`. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: nope !! i tried with all protocols, it's the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend neo4j Aura. It is a fully managed cloud service and has a hassle free connection to a database. It is also has a free tier to try. See sample script to connect into it:

> https://neo4j.com/cloud/aura/

```
import neo4j,sys
link = "bolt://" + sys.argv[1]
print(f"Trying to connect to:  {link}")
#format of uri is <9999>.databases.neo4j.io

def exp():
    try:
        x = neo4j.GraphDatabase.driver(link, auth=("neo4j", "my_pswd"))

        print(x.verify_connectivity())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
link = "bolt+ssc://" + sys.argv[1]
```

or

```
link = "neo4j+ssc://" + sys.argv[1]
```

instead of

```
link = "bolt://" + sys.argv[1]
```

The '+ssc' variants are URI schemes for encrypted sessions that do not check certificates.
Refer to the [Neo4j Driver manual](https://neo4j.com/docs/driver-manual/4.0/client-applications/#driver-configuration-examples) for more details on the connection URI.
Notes from the [Neo4j migration guide](https://neo4j.com/docs/upgrade-migration-guide/current/migration/drivers/new-uri-schemes/)